# ASP.Net MVC - Assign value from Jquery to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have a value in Jquery. I need to apply that value to a view which has a model.
For example, I need to do assign it to the following:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.programid)
```

the variable that I am trying to store in model.programid is called progid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#programid').val(...)
```

If you're in an editor template, you'll need to add `@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`

Comment: Mines is slighly more complicated than the above. I have @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.program.programid). Just wondering how I would reference it as not working. Thank you.

Comment: The `.`s become `_`s, as you can see in the page source.